# Test Action of Redux-thunk use JEST

Tags: unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I want to write a test for Axios use Jest Framework. I'm using Redux.

Here is my function **get-request** of **Axios**

```js
export const getRequest = a => dispatch => {
  return axios
    .get(a)
    .then(function(response) {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: response.data
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      dispatch({ type: ERROR_DATA, payload: { status: error.response.status, statusText: error.response.statusText } });
    });
};
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_DATA = 'FETCH_DATA';
export const ERROR_DATA = 'ERROR_DATA';

export const getRequest = a => dispatch => {
  return axios
    .get(a)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: response.data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch({ type: ERROR_DATA, payload: { status: error.response.status, statusText: error.response.statusText } });
    });
};
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { getRequest, FETCH_DATA, ERROR_DATA } from './';

describe('getRequest', () => {
  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  it('should get data and dispatch action correctly', async () => {
    const axiosGetSpyOn = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: 'mocked data' });
    await getRequest('jest')(dispatch);
    expect(axiosGetSpyOn).toBeCalledWith('jest');
    expect(dispatch).toBeCalledWith({ type: FETCH_DATA, payload: 'mocked data' });
    axiosGetSpyOn.mockRestore();
  });

  it('should dispatch error', async () => {
    const error = {
      response: {
        status: 400,
        statusText: 'client error'
      }
    };
    const axiosGetSpyOn = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockRejectedValueOnce(error);
    await getRequest('ts')(dispatch);
    expect(axiosGetSpyOn).toBeCalledWith('ts');
    expect(dispatch).toBeCalledWith({ type: ERROR_DATA, payload: error.response });
    axiosGetSpyOn.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Unit test result and coverage:

```sh
 PASS  45062447/index.spec.ts
  getRequest
    ✓ should get data and dispatch action correctly (9ms)
    ✓ should dispatch error (2ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.551s, estimated 3s
```

Here is the code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/45062447